# Within BOE XI, using the Java SDK, when scheduling a report, is there a way to store some string attributes onto the actual instance?

Tags: java, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Within BOE 4, using the Java SDK, when scheduling a report, is there a way to store some string attributes onto the actual instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom properties to any CMS object.  For example:

```
IInfoObjects ios = oInfoStore.query("select * from ci_infoobjects where si_id = 5047825");
IInfoObject io = (IInfoObject) ios.get(0);
io.properties().add("MY_TESTPROP","test value",0);
oInfoStore.schedule(ios);
```

You could then retrieve the property with a regular CMS query:

```
select my_testprop from ci_infoobjects where si_parentid = 5047825
```

Note that this works just fine when scheduling one-time instances.  If you're scheduling a *recurring* instance, then the custom property will be applied to the *recurring* instance itself, but not to the instances that the schedule produces.